# AWS SSO authorization for EKS fails to call sts:AssumeRole

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubectl, amazon-eks, aws-sso

I'm migrating to AWS SSO for cli access, which has worked for everything except for kubectl so far.
While troubleshooting it I followed a few guides, which means I ended up with some cargo-cult behaviour, and I'm obviously missing something in my mental model.

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "<redacted>",
    "Account": "<redacted>",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::<redacted>:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_DeveloperReadonly_a6a1426b0fdf9f87/<my username>"
}
```

**kubectl get pods**

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts:::assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_DeveloperReadonly_a6a1426b0fdf9f87/ is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam:::role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/us-east-2/AWSReservedSSO_DeveloperReadonly_a6a1426b0fdf9f87

It's amusing that it seems to be trying to assume the same role that it's already using, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

~/.aws/config (subset - I have other profiles, but they aren't relevant here)

```
[default]
region = us-east-2
output = json

[profile default]
sso_start_url = https://<redacted>.awsapps.com/start
sso_account_id = <redacted>
sso_role_name = DeveloperReadonly
region = us-east-2
sso_region = us-east-2
output = json
```

~/.kube/config (with clusters removed)

```
apiVersion: v1
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-east-2:<redacted>:cluster/foo
    user: ro
  name: ro
current-context: ro
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: ro
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-east-2
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - foo
      - --role
      - arn:aws:iam::<redacted>:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/us-east-2/AWSReservedSSO_DeveloperReadonly_a6a1426b0fdf9f87
      command: aws
      env: null
```

aws-auth mapRoles snippet

```
- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<redacted>:role/AWSReservedSSO_DeveloperReadonly_a6a1426b0fdf9f87
  username: "devread:{{SessionName}}"
  groups:
    - view
```

What obvious thing am I missing? I've reviewed the other stackoverflow posts with similar issues, but none had the **arn:aws:sts:::assumed-role** ->  **arn:aws:iam:::role** path.

Comment: Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65660833/aws-eks-and-aws-sso-rbac-authentication-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*.aws/config* had a subtle error - `[profile default]` isn't meaningful, so the two blocks should have been merged into `[default]`. Only the non-default profiles should have profile in the name.

```
[default]
sso_start_url = https://<redacted>.awsapps.com/start
sso_account_id = <redacted>
sso_role_name = DeveloperReadonly
region = us-east-2
sso_region = us-east-2
output = json

[profile rw]
sso_start_url = https://<redacted>.awsapps.com/start
sso_account_id = <redacted>
sso_role_name = DeveloperReadWrite
region = us-east-2
sso_region = us-east-2
output = json
```

I also changed *.kube/config* to get the token based on the profile instead of naming the role explicitly. This fixed the AssumeRole failing since it used the existing role.

```
apiVersion: v1
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-east-2:<redacted>:cluster/foo
    user: ro
  name: ro
current-context: ro
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: ro
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-east-2
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - foo
      - --profile
      - default
      command: aws
      env: null
```

I can now run `kubectl config use-context ro` or the other profiles I've defined (omitted for brevity).

On a related note, I had some trouble getting an older terraform version to work since the s3 backend didn't handle sso. [aws-vault](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault/) solved this for me